# Get last 24 hours data from mongo with mule4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

How can I used the mongodb component "find documents" to get the last 24 hours data from collection?

I tried the following query in the component but it didn't work.

Sample:

```
"createdAt" :  { $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000) }
```

How I can get the last data (24 hours) from mongo?

Comment: Please share the XML for the full operation. Also, what exactly didn't work? If there is an error or results please share.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying to use Java or MEL syntax in Mule 4 to construct the JSON that is used for the MongoDB query. In Mule 4 you need to use [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/dataweave) as the expression language. An expression in DataWeave to generate something similar could be:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "createdAt" :  { 
        "\$gte": (now() - |P1D|) as String { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"}
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "createdAt": {
    "$gte": "2022-10-18T12:06:19Z"
  }
}
```

If you need a different date time format you can tinker with the format in the expression.

Note that DataWeave supports [date arithmetic with periods of time](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-add-and-subtract-time) so you don't need to use hacks like subtracting a number of milliseconds. `|P1D|` is a period of 1 day.

Comment: This answers uses Mule expressions. If you are trying to use pure MongoDB features you need a different solution.